# Javascript / React list titles from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have some data in a react project and I need to display the titles in a list.

Here is the data:

```
   const data = [
    {
        "things":[
            {
                "id":"1",
                "subdata":{
                    "date":{
                        "exp":"2018-17-23"
                    },
                    "titles":[
                        {
                            "title":"title1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title":"title2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

How can I list the title values in a

  { title value here }

loop?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to do a loop?

Comment: Yes please to get the titles data

Comment: Do you want to loop over all "titles" in multiple "things"? Also, if you put your real data structure in your question I think it'll be easier to answer.

Comment: In this case I just want to loop titles and display to 2 titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through titles of just first thing and log it:

```
data[0].things[0].subdata.titles.forEach(obj => {
  console.log(obj.title)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[0].things.map(({ subdata }) => subdata.titles.map(({ title }) => console.log(title)))
```

Comment: Given the context of the question, use a .forEach instead of a .map. This is also less performant with the use of two .map calls. :|

Comment: We cant really know if things is array with only one object or multiple objects. Also he wants to use it with React where forEach dosent return anything causing nothing to render.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[0].things[0].subdata.titles.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.title));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the titles in a new array, you could use `.map`

```
const allTitles = data[0].things[0].subdata.titles.map(title => title.title);

console.log(allTitles);

// outputs ["title1", "title2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing to individual indexes within the array, @kevin Porche, I think you should have a function automatically know the indexes and build your titles for you.

Here is a code sample that would build your titles even when you have a lot of items within `data`
eg:

```
const data = [{things: []}, {things: []} ];
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "things": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "subdata": {
                    "date": {
                        "exp": "2018-17-23"
                    },
                    "titles": [
                        {
                            "title": "title1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "title2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

const yourTitles = [];
data.map(({ things }) => {
    things.map(({ subdata: { titles } }) => {           
        titles.map(({ title }) => {
            yourTitles.push(title);
        });        
    })
});

console.log(yourTitles);
```